# iis application pool stops

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, application-pool

in my server iis application pool suddenly stops and my website closed
i get this error have you got any idea
error says me An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
i dont understan where is the problem is it a server problem or website code problem

```
`Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23796, time stamp: 0x59029714
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000001a06d
Faulting process id: 0x1eac
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2cf1dc0fcbf01
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 013d9fcc-3b30-11e7-895c-005056943608

Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT

Process ID: 7852

Exception: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException

Message: You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.

StackTrace:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at RestSharp.Http.RequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult result, Action`1 callback)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(Exception E)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.ProcessWriteCallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.CallDone(ConnectionReturnResult returnResult)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.IOError(Exception exception, Boolean willThrow)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ResumeIOWorker(Object result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.WakeupPendingIO(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.FinishHandshake(Exception e, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ReadFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32 bytes)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped`
```